# "Você devia ficar calado" ou "Você devia de ficar calado."?

Tags: verbos, preposições, regionalismo

Em certas regiões do sudeste brasileiro, principalmente no interior de Minas Gerais e Espírito Santo, é comum ouvirmos o acréscimo da preposição *de* após determinados verbos, principalmente o verbo precisar. Exemplos:

> - "Tu devias **de** ter ido ao enterro."
> - "Você devia **de** ter dito a verdade."
> - "Preciso **de** comprar carne."
> - "Preciso **de** falar com ela."
> - "Eu preciso **de** fazer um empréstimo."
> - "Para ser aeromoça, tu precisas **de** fazer um curso"

Aos meus ouvidos de carioca da gema, soa estranho.  Pergunto então, na língua escrita e na língua falada formal,

1. Trata-se de um regionalismo correto e aceito em qualquer situação?
2. Embora idiomático e de uso corrente em certas regiões, é errado falar assim?
3. Os exemplos acima estão corretos?

Comment: Interessante pergunta.

Comment: O título não está muito bem escolhido, porque _dever_ e _precisar_ têm comportamentos distintos. Em Portugal, _de_ é praticamente obrigatório com _precisar_, mas, com _dever_, _de_ é relativamente incomum.

Comment: @Artefacto   "com precisar, o *de* é **praticamente obrigatório** ?   Isso, indiretamente, significa que omitir o *de* é **praticamente errado** ?

Comment: Os primeiros 2 exemplos em Portugal nunca seriam ditos. Os outros sim, são normais e a maneira mais comum de dizer.

Comment: @bad_coder _dever de_ é certamente usado por muita gente (não tanto na escrita), embora talvez mais nas pessoas mais velhas. Nunca é feita é a distinção entre modalidade epistémica e deôntica, como algum gramático se lembrou de inventar -- [exemplos de usos nos dois sentidos](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22deve%20de%20haver%22%20site:publico.pt)

Comment: @Artefacto achei engraçado o URL que incluiste ser do jornal Público e todas as ocorrências serem de discursos políticos. Enfim, fico sem saber se é representativo se não. Mas, tenho as minhas dúvidas, talvez quisessem citar os políticos em momentos menos conseguidos gramaticalmente , ou talvez lhes tenham distorcido as citações de modo propositado, de qualquer maneira não acho as 50 ocorrências especialmente significativas...

Comment: @bad_coder procurei especificamente por "deve de haver" para evitar falsos positivos. Não inclui portanto todos os resultados sequer em publico.pt. Acho estranho que não estejas familiarizado com a construção; há pessoas que a usam muito, embora não negue que seja uma forma desfavorecida na escrita. Quanto à correção, pelo menos no sentido epistémico, não há dúvidas, como atestam variadíssimas fontes. E o que não falta são exemplos  na literatura (incluindo nos Lusíadas por exemplo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os casos "dever" e "precisar" são na realidade distintos:

- **dever (de) + infinitivo**
  Originalmente o uso da preposição nesse caso denotava uma possibilidade, uma suposição ("deve de chover hoje") ao invés de uma certeza ou obrigação, como o uso sem "de" denota - mas correntemente, também em Portugal, a preposição costuma ser omitida mesmo no sentido de possibilidade. (Fonte: [questão](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dever-de/4260) do Ciberdúvidas.)
- **precisar (de) + infinitivo**
  Ambos (com e sem a preposição) estão corretos, com "de" sendo sempre usado em pt-PT e opcional (e menos comum) em pt-BR. (Fontes e detalhes abaixo.)

Às perguntas:

> 1. Trata-se de um regionalismo correto e aceito em qualquer situação?

Com "precisar", sim, é correto sempre - mas naturalmente pode causar estranhamento ao ponto de soar errado para quem não está habituado. No caso de "dever", deve-se omitir a preposição se o significado não for o de suposição (e, mesmo nesse último caso, pode-se omiti-lo).

> 2. Embora idiomático e de uso corrente em certas regiões, é errado falar assim?

Com "precisar", não, não é errado - em Portugal inclusive é o padrão. Já um "dever de fazer" que indica obrigação ao invés de suposição está "errado": deve ser evitado em contextos formais.

> 3. Os exemplos acima estão corretos?

Os dois primeiros parecem usar "dever de ter feito" com o sentido de obrigação, caso em que o "de" deveria ser omitido. Os demais exemplos estão corretos.

---

Mais detalhes sobre o caso **precisar (de) + infinitivo**:

Como coloca esse [site](https://aprendaepratique.com/gramatica/precisar-ou-precisar-de/) de português para estrangeiros:

> Quando um segundo verbo vier depois de precisar, não é necessário usar a preposição “de” para unir os dois verbos.

E melhor esclarecido ainda no Ciberdúvidas [nessa pergunta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/precisarprecisar-de/3346) (meu grifo):

> Segundo o «Dicionário das Questões Vernáculas» de Napoleão Mendes de Almeida, «seguidos de infinitivo, precisar e necessitar **vêm sem ou com de**: Precisamos acabar com estes passeios - O partido liberal precisa de mover a incredulidade pública - Os libertos necessitam desmentir esses receios - O que necessitaremos de apurar é audácia.»

e, especialmente, [nessa](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/preciso-de-estudar-e-preciso-estudar/22875):

> «Na actual norma portuguesa da língua, este verbo, quando na acepção de "ter necessidade de", pede objecto indirecto*; há, porém, bom número de abonações de autores portugueses clássicos, como Camilo e Bocage, que o empregam com transitividade directa**; na verdade, na língua, a regência deste verbo oscila entre uma coisa e outra, com peso maior para o objecto indirecto, tanto no Brasil como em Portugal, excepto quando a ele se segue outro verbo no infinitivo, caso em que, em Portugal, se usa sempre seguido de preposição (preciso de fazer, precisava de sair, precisou de se explicar), enquanto, no Brasil, tal emprego tem vindo a rarear (preciso fazer, precisava sair, precisou explicar-se).»1
>
> O facto de um dado uso ser menos frequente não quer dizer que passe a ser classificado como uso incorrecto.
>
> Acresce que há atestações de precisar de + infinitivo em autores brasileiros da segunda metade do século XX:
> «Delfino precisava de ser prudente.» António Callado — A Madona de Cedro, 1957.
> «— Eu precisava de ter uma lembrança dela»; «Este precisava de feri-lo, vingar a história dos bois.» Osman Lins — O Fiel e a Pedra, 1961.
> «Ruth notou que a bata branca de Antonio mudara de cor, precisava de ser lavada.» Antonio Olinto — Sangue na Floresta, 1993.
>
> *com recurso à preposição
> **sem recurso à preposição
>
> 1 Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa, Lisboa, Tema e Debates, 2003

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137270/discussion-on-answer-by-stafusa-voce-devia-ficar-calado-ou-voce-devia-de-fica).